# Element to move with background on resize

Tags: css, html

I’m currently building a single page scrolling website.

On the second page I'm using a background with the background-size:cover attribute. Basically I want an element to sit on top of the background but move in correspondence with the background on resize, even if that means the element moves out of the viewport.

Is this possible?

What I've tried so far:

```
.background {
width:100%; 
height:100vh; 
margin:0;
background-image: url('Studio.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 80% 0%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

#image {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
background-image: url('lamp.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
position: absolute;
}
```

I've mocked up a diagram to better explain what I'm trying to achieve:

The first diagram shows how the layout looks in a full size viewport. 
The second diagram shows how I want the layout to look when the viewport is resized... so the image element moves in relation to the background, out of the view port.

[Link to first diagram](http://i61.tinypic.com/2dwbuon.png)

[Link to second diagram](http://i59.tinypic.com/33c6bf6.png)

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ Probably, but we don't know what you're talking about without seeing your code. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Added code to question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like parallax scrolling or position:fixed on your element.

Comment: position:fixed doesn't let the element move relative to the background.